# Gerrit admin not able to delete branch via UI

Tags: git, gerrit

[image]

I am  Gerrit Admin and I am not able to delete branch via the web UI. I am getting the following error.

Version 2.10

Comment: any info in `logs/error_log`?

Comment: nope..cant see anything related to this

Comment: My developers are also getting errors while trying to create branches via UI, although they can d the same via CLI (through git commands)

Comment: Are you running a proxy (Apache) in front of Gerrit? Anything in the log files there? What do your browser's developer tools say regarding the response headers - is that coming from Gerrit/Jetty or the proxy? Or are you running Gerrit within Tomcat?

Comment: Hey it is fixed. I had to set "AllowEncodedSlashes On" in my httpd.conf.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. In my firebug console I saw that the requests were failing for those URLs which had encoded slashes in them

Answer (score 0):

I had to set

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

in my `httpd.conf` settings, since I am hosting Gerrit behind an Apache2 server.

See [Gerrit Reverse Proxy Documentation](http://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.10/config-reverseproxy.html#_apache_2_configuration).